# Laravel Call to a member function getName() on null Error

Tags: php, laravel

I have a custom method that I use in my Laravel helper class:

```
public static function get_lang()
{
    $title_tag = __( request()->path() . '.title_tag' );
    if( ( request()->route()->getName() !== 'index' ) ) {
        abort( 404 );
    }
}
```

When accessed from a browser on the Web it runs great, no problem.

However, when ran on the CLI with this Artisan command, I'm getting an error:

```
php artisan route:list
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error

Call to a member function getName() on null

at app/Helpers/Helper.php:11
public static function get_lang()
{
    $title_tag = __( request()->path() . '.title_tag' );
    if( ( request()->route()->getName() !== 'index' ) ) {
        abort( 404 );
    }
}
```

How can I add a check to verify getName() isn't null to prevent from getting this error?

Comment: "*[...] check to verify `getName()` isn't `null` [...]*" - You're missing what your error is saying; `request()->route()` is `null`, not `getName()`. `null->getName()` isn't valid. Never assume the result of a method, always check, either via the answer below, or if on PHP8, `request()?->route()?->getName()` (the `null-safe operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CLI/console, there's no `request()`, nor is there a `request()->route()` to get a name for.

You might consider having your helper check `app()->runningInConsole()` and return a default there.

Comment: I like this approach since I can use it on all the code that is meant to be ran on the Web and not the console. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you run the command there's no request route. Something like this would solve the issue where `getName()` is not able to be returned on a non-object.

```
public static function get_lang()
{
    $title_tag = __( request()->path() . '.title_tag' );

    // Validate that request()->route() is not null
    if(request()->route()) {
       if( ( request()->route()->getName() !== 'index' ) ) {
          abort( 404 );
       }
    }
}
```